# PHP: Write in line x with FPDF / FPDI

Tags: php, function, pdf, fpdf

I‘m currently developing a function that fills out a PDF template for me with some informations. I'm looking now for a way to simplify the process. The problem is that I'm currently filling out the PDF this way:

```
$pdf->SetXY(40, 83);
$pdf->Write(2, 'THIS IS JUST A TEST');
```

The problem with this is that this not 100 % exactly. So is there a way to do something like:

```
$line = 5;
$pdf->Write(5, centered ,'Test');
```

So In this case I'm expecting Test as a centered text in line 5. If this is not possible, what is the best way to do this at the moment?

Comment: SetXY is very exact. Why should this `SetXY(40, 83)` not be exact enough?

Comment: It is but its also very complicated and i need to check the PDF thousends of times if everything is ok

Comment: Look into using the `cell` method instead of using `write`. As Odan said, `write` is used for precision placement. Using `cell` allows you to position the data horizontally on a line and can, optionally, take care of getting you to the next line.